How can I enable logging on my huggingface model that I'm using an inference point (api) for?
The catch is that I'm not using the huggingface 'transformers' library, since i'm not running the models locally but am using an inference point to the model on HF (similar to how we use the Openai api).
I've checked documentation for logging, but they all involve using the transformers library. Is there a way i can still manage to log data from my model here?
Here's the script i'm working on.
import os
from huggingface_hub import InferenceClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json

load_dotenv()
repo_id = "microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct"

llm_client = InferenceClient(
    model=repo_id,
    timeout=120,
)

def call_llm(inference_client: InferenceClient, prompt: str):

    response = inference_client.post(
        json={
            "inputs": prompt,
            "parameters": {"max_new_tokens": 300},
            "task": "text-generation",
        },
    )

    return json.loads(response.decode())[0]["generated_text"]

response = call_llm(llm_client, "Give me a tutorial on how to use huggingface models via api on my laptop, without having to download the model locally. Include code snippets and explanations.")

print(response)

As i mentioned, I've wanted to enable logging while using the api, and not running the model locally using transformers. Do let me know if there's a way to achieve this.
